# Button generate a random URL

Tags: functions, buttons

I'm trying to add a Button, which generates a random URL every time it's clicked.

I found :

```
<a href="<?php echo ( "http://meet.jit.si/" . rand(1000, 9000) )?>" target="_blank"> click here </a>
```

But I have no idea where to post this into.

Comment: What's your question? Does your code not work? What doesn't it do that you need it to do? Is this related to WordPress?

Comment: Yes, its related to Wordpress.
I added a button on my website, but I have no idea, where to post this function to make it work for this button.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your code works as written.

Alternatively, you can generate an alphanumeric string using [`uniqid()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)...

```
<a href="http://meet.jit.si/<?php echo uniqid()?>" target="_blank"> click here </a>
```

---

**EDIT:** Modified code based on additional information.

This should create a shortcode that allows you to easily add a button to a unique meeting link by adding `[rand_jitsi_btn]` to a post/page:

```
// hook our shortcode creation to `init` so that WordPress has time to initialize properly
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_shortcode' );
function add_custom_shortcode() {
    add_shortcode( 'rand_jitsi_btn', 'create_rand_jitsi_btn' );
}
// Code to create the button
function create_rand_jitsi_btn() {
    return '<a href="http://meet.jit.si/' . uniqid() . '" target="_blank"> Launch Meeting </a>';
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it *should* work if you place it in your child theme's `functions.php` file.

Note: You can use something like `random_int()` instead of `uniqid()` if you need *numeric* randoms.

Comment: Thank you, but where do I add this code In Wordpress?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the context of your question. It's not clear what you intend to do.

Comment: Okay:
I want to create a unique jitsi-meeting-room for every visitor, who clicks on the button "create meeting room". Every visitor needs a unique URL (e.g. http://meet.jit.si/12345) so no visitor gets in the same meeting room. All I can do is to create a Button with a normal link - but I don't know where to give this button a function

Answer (score 0):

You could create a shortcode for the button and use that for inserting a link with a random Jitsi room anywhere in the content of your site or even in the widgets. Make the button label a variable in the shortcode so that you can further customise it.